# Hand brake up and you drive new car

Tags: brakes

I drive my new car for 5km ar 60km/h with hsnd brack up and i feel little smell when stop on near to rear wheel. Now i will remove foot from brack when start driving there is a noise. Need sugestion and precautionary measures

Answer (score 2):

For precaution : always check the dashboard lights after ignition! If the ' ! ' light is on , it means the handbrake is also on too. After releasing the handbrake the light switches off .If you see the light on when the handbrake is released , then it means you have worned out your brakes .
Hand brake lever usually activates the rear brakes . Probable source of damage is at the rear .The brake shoes may have knocked off from their position and causing the noise .
Park your car at a incline and turn on only the handbrake (no gear or foot brake) keep the ignition on . If the car slips then definitely your rear brake shoes/ disk /drum / hub has been heavily damaged. Also if your car is a rear wheel drive, have the rear differential and prop shaft checked .
You are better off to a dealer as there is a chance you can slip some of the damages under warranty .

Comment: Thank you for the response and welcome to Stack Exchange! We strive for high-quality answers to the questions on this website. Though you have a lot of good information, we ask that you stick to typical rules for sentence structure, such as proper punctuation. Could you please edit your response to use periods instead of exclamation points, where appropriate. Thanks!